# what do I need to change in my CSS here

Tags: html, css

I used to have tables before to display the content and people here advised me to remove tables and use CSS floating for better styling.

I am new to everything. My Problem is I have content and side bar. I want it to be displayed like

```
content           | Sidebar
```

But Now with the current styling I have It is displaying like

```
content
|
Sidebar
```

Can you please correct me.

```
       <style type="text/css">

   .csscontent
    {

          margin-right: 500px;



    }

   .csssidebar
    {
        float: right;
        width: 500px;
        background: darkgreen;
       /*  height:500px; */



    }


</style>
```

If I add

```
  <div class="Content">
  all the content
 <div class="sidebar">
 <Image>
 </div>
```

If I add sidebar inside the content the image is getting displayed below the content leaving right-margin of 500px.

If I add sidebar outside of the content the image is getting displayed below the content.

```
  <div class="Content">
  all the content
  </div>

   <div class="sidebar">
   <Image>
  </div>
```

**I want both content and side bar to be displayed side by side**

Comment: You know your class names differ in markup/css?

Comment: dear see my answer and let me if anything else you want. see demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML file you first need to set the floating elements, followed by the none floating ones. Because the floating element is going to block the entire "level" of the website and the floating elements are placed below.

So your html should look like this:

```
   <div class="sidebar">
   <Image>
  </div>
  <div class="Content">
  all the content
  </div>
```

Other then that it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Float both to the left so they stack up against each other.

```
    .Content
    {
          margin-right: 500px; 
          float: left; 
    }

   .sidebar
    {
        float: left;
        width: 500px;
        background: darkgreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add float to .csscontent class like

```
 .csscontent
    {
          margin-right: 500px;
          Float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.content, .sidebar {
  float: left;
}
```

Floating both divs left like the above will display both inline.

You can then apply specific styling to each class. Assigning a width to .content will then determine where .sidebar appears...

Answer (score 1):

Or if all you want is to float the sidebar to the right, without floating the content, you should put the sidebar above the content in the HTML.

Of course, you still need to correct the class names...

Answer (score 1):

you can add a wrapper for both elements.

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
      all the content
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
      <img/>
  </div>

</div>

div#wrapper {
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:800px;
}

div#content {
     float:left;
     width:600px;
} 

 div#sidebar {
     float:right;
     width:200px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't see where your wrapper is useful. And why are you changing the widths from the original?

Answer (score 1):

see fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g42x2/1/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g42x2/1/embedded/result/

SS:

[image]